# Draw vertical line using CSS and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a horizontal timeline and I have most of the stuff resolved besides drawing the vertical line from the bullet to the horizontal line.

What I am trying to achieve is to connect the bullets from `even` and `odd` class to the horizontal line at the middle. Since the height and the width of the `div.even` and `div.odd` might be different, I think I need to use JQuery to know the appropriate height of the vertical line to each of the `div.even` and `div.odd`

Here is my work

```css
.timeline-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.timeline-container .odd, .timeline-container .even {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;

  
}


.odd {
  padding-bottom:1px;
  
}

.even:before {
  content: "\2219 ";
  width: 50px;
  position:relative;
  left: 50%;
}

.odd:after {
  content: "\2219";
  position: relative;
  left:50%;
}

.even {
  top: 200px;
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="timeline">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1>Timeline</h1>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        
        
        <div class="timeline-container">
          
          <hr style="position:absolute; top: 40%; border:1px solid #717171; width:100%"/>
          
          <div style="position: absolute; left:416px; top:77px; border-left: 1px solid black; ">
          
          </div>
           <div class="odd">
             <h5>Year 2014</h5>
          </div>
          
           <div class="even">
             <h4>March 2015 achievement</h4>
             <p>Short description that best describe the event</p>
          </div>  
          
           <div class="odd test">
             <h4>March 2015 achievement</h4>
             <p>Short description that best describe the event</p>          
          </div> 
          
          <hr width="1" size="100" style="position: absolute; border:1px solid #717171;z-index:20" >
          
          <div class="even">
             <h4>March 2015 achievement</h4>
             <p>Short description that best describe the event</p>
          </div>           
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ajbvgcj/

I am trying to draw the vertical line by using `hr` by setting the width to be 1 and sizes to be the height I wanted, but it seems not working.

```
<hr width="1" size="100" style="position: absolute; left: 30px; top: 30px; border:1px solid #717171;z-index:20" >
```

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: You've said "with CSS" but your question contains just HTML and a link. Any code, markup, etc. related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. If the question doesn't make sense and can't be answered without the link, it's not appropriate for this site. Instead, put the [**minimum** complete example](/help/mcve) **in** the question (ideally in this case using Stack Snippets [the `<>` toolbar button], which support CSS and HTML).

Comment: do you have any img to show what you want to achieve here?

Comment: Why are you trying to draw a vertical line with an element designed for horizontal layout? Surely this is just a case of adding a border to an element that runs the full height of the timeline?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: Yes. Another alternative will be creating empty div with border with it,

Comment: @Venugopal: Click run code snippet or simply go to the jsfiddle to see the result. What I am trying to do is connecting the bullet to the horizontal line at the middle.

Answer (score -1):

```css
      div {
           min-height:300px;
           border-left: 1px solid black;
         }
```

Apply this css to hr , It will be a vertical line. Please check and respond

Answer (score -1):

Why HR? Just use a div and absolute position it:

```
div.class {
    position: absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    min-height:300px;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

The hr will only complicate things. It was made as a horizontal ruler, hence the name `<hr>`.

Comment: #Rinon- We can better have just     min-height:300px; 
border-left: 1px solid black;